# (Android Studio) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraint(all of em) in package (my stuff)

Tags: android, xml

Using Android Studio to create a game, and I'm trying to create a start screen menu XML. By this I mean our professor gave us one to straight up copy, which I did.

However, I get the following errors:

```
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintHorizontal_bias' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
C:\Users\firstlast\AndroidStudioProjects\FlappyBird\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_bird.xml
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(11) No resource identi`fier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
C:\Users\firstlast\AndroidStudioProjects\FlappyBird\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_bird.xml
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintHorizontal_bias' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf' in package 'edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    tools:context="edu.udel.myname.FlappyBird.bird.FlappyBirdActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_1"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highScores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:text="Play"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/demo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:text="Instructions"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/quit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:text="Quit"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You will most likely not get much of a response on this site as far as helping you properly copy code for a homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute "layout_constraintHorizontal_bias" is for the [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). But, in your layout file, there's a LinearLayout.

Try replacing that LinearLayout with a ConstraintLayout.

You may need to also add

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

to the dependencies block in your build.gradle file for this app module.